# I made a class for A tags in a special div, but it applies to whole website

Tags: css

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro  a:active, a:visited, a:link { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #dddddd; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    padding: 10px; 
}

div.browseBuildsArea-pro  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #dddddd; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); padding: 10px;
}
```

Links are like this:

```
<div class="browseBuildsArea-pro">
<div class="build-poster">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, the CSS attributes above applies to all `a` tags in website. This A class should only work under `browseBuildsArea-pro` class of `div`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look on how [CSS-Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) work.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this:

```
div.browseBuildsArea-pro  A:active, 
div.browseBuildsArea-pro  A:visited, 
div.browseBuildsArea-pro  A:link { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #dddddd; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    padding: 10px; 
}
```

The `div.browseBuildsArea-pro` doesn't carry past the comma automatically.